# Flow is rounding numbers to 3 decimals on double apex defined variable

Tags: visual-workflow, double

I have an apex-defined variable of type double I'm using in a flow. I need to be able to assign a number with 4 decimals to it, but it's always rounding to 3 dps on assignment.

I can't set a limit on this variable that I can see, unless I'm missing something obvious.

The same is happening with using fields of custom objects where the field decimal is set to 4, when using them in a flow, the assignment is always rounding at 3 dps. However, number variables defined inside the flow with decimals set to 4 appear as expected.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!